# Unable to install magento2.4.3 in linux facing : No space left on device error

Tags: php, elasticsearch, magento2

file_put_contents(/var/www/magento/app/etc/vendor_path.php): failed to open stream: No space left on device

this error is coming even there is 12 gb space empty in the disk

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to Elasticsearch?

Comment: no I'm not sure i think this problem is related to inodes in linux